# Should I always implement MVC pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller

MVC is great but do I always need it? I understand that MVC makes your applications meaningful, structured/organized and reusable. What if I have a function that is called from only one place and is very unlikely to be used elsewhere in my project. Do I need to create a controller for it? Is it worth it?

Thanks for all inputs.

Comment: A controller plays a very specific role within an MVC pattern.  If your function acts like a controller then should probably make it one.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I have a function that is called from only one place and is
>   very unlikely to be used elsewhere in my project.
>   Do I need to create a controller for it?

I would make it a helper class like a static class. No need to make a controller out of it.

> Should I always implement MVC pattern?

no. We in our team, uses MVC with MVVM pattern using knockoutjs. No need to always follow the MVC pattern. If I create a desktop app, I use Three-tier